# Validate element is selected; Cannot find unique element

Tags: java, selenium, automation, xtend

I cannot find the unique element for me to validate if this element is selected. Need help.  [see attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJWTj.png) for the elements possible.

```
   var attr = findElement(By.xpath("//theme-item[@class='list-group-item 
   xpath-themes-list-item active ng-star-inserted']")).getText()
            log("!!")
                if (attr.contains("Infor M3A Theme"))
                {

  Assert.assertTrue(findElement(By.xpath("//theme-item[@class='list-group- 
  item xpath-themes-list-item active ng-star-inserted']")).isSelected, 
  "Incorrect Theme selected")
                    log("Infor M3A Theme Selected")
                    findElement(By.xpath("//* 
   [text()='back']")).click

   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@aria-label='Close Global 
   Navigation' and contains(@data-title,'CLOSE')]")).click();

                }
                else
                {
                    Assert.fail("Theme Validation failed")
                }
```

its much better if i can validate by using the element class with active to really ensure that, that element is selected since that is a good identifier

Comment: Try this : `//theme-item[contains(@class,'list-item') and contains(@class,'active')]`. Add `//a` at the end if required.

Comment: it cannot detect this element

Answer (score 0):

you can try with the below xpath.

```
//theme-item[contains(@class,'list-item active')]//a
```

Comment: it cannot detect this element

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using class identifier, you can go for linktext if your text is constant.

```
driver.findElement(By.linktext(" *** M3A Theme"));
```

or you can directly search for the text like this

```
driver.finElement(By.xpath("//a[@text='*** M3A Theme']"));
```

If your text is not constant, you can go with contains text using xpath

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()[contains(.,'M3A Theme')]]"));
```

**Note:**

To fetch class:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("theme-item[class = 'list-group-item 
xpath-themes-list-item active']"));
```

I believe your class name is dynamic and it will be `list-group-item xpath-themes-list-item` for all the elements, once you click on any option,class name will change to `list-group-item xpath-themes-list-item active`.

So to verify if its selected or not, first you click using `linktext`. Then you go with the above locator that I've provided and check for `isDisplayed()`. By this way you can verify whether your option is selected or not

Comment: hello this works. but i need to get the class wherein there is an identifier "active" to verify that the theme is selected. but that class is fro different tab (please see screenshot) do you know how to?

Comment: I've made changes in my answer after **Note:**. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find Parent element containing highlighted theme

   ```
   List<WebElement> parent = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".list-group-item.
   xpath-themes-list-item.active"));
   ```
2. Find child element i.e. tag 'a' inside parent

   ```
   WebElement themeElement = parent.findElement(By.tagName('a'));
   ```
3. Find theme name

   ```
   themeElement.getText();
   ```

Comment: it cannot detect the css selector element

Comment: @MaryMadelynnCruz - you means `By.cssSelector` method is not available or `cssSelector` locator is not working ?

Comment: it is not working. No such element is resulting on my script

Comment: possibly can be a wait issue, can you try y putting wait before `findElement`

Comment: yup there are time that the element is found but its taking almost 90 seconds for that element. is there a way to optimize this case?

Comment: no dom issues related to load time we cannot resolve, as they may be happening due to low internet bandwidth,but if element is loading between 30-90 sec then we can reduce time using Explicit waits as soon as element is loaded in DOM, it will be clicked.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use XPath [`contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) function in order to match the `theme-item` which is active.
2. Once done you can utilize [`descendant` axe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/descendant) to find its child [`a`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) element
3. It's better to use [WebDriverWait](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/) in order to ensure that the element is really present and can be interacted with

Putting everything together:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        .until(ExpectedConditions
                .elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//theme-item[contains(@class,'active')]/descendant::a")))
        .click();
```

Going forward please avoid posting [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/whatis/whatis_htmldom.asp) as image, the chance of getting a good response will be much better if you add code instead.